# Can someone please thoroughly explain what a URI is?

Tags: uri

I understand it has something to do with databases but I am not exactly sure what it does.. I looked on the android developer page and they don't explain it very well.

Comment: "Can someone explain this utterly google-able and wikipedia-covered acronym in maybe three pages of SO answer?"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the context but URI generally refers to Uniform Resource Identifier. See Wikipedia for more:

> In information technology, a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a
>   string of characters used to identify a resource. Such identification
>   enables interaction with representations of the resource over a
>   network, typically the World Wide Web, using specific protocols.
>   Schemes specifying a concrete syntax and associated protocols define
>   each URI. The most common form of URI is the Uniform Resource Locator
>   (URL), frequently referred to informally as a web address. More rarely
>   seen in usage is the Uniform Resource Name (URN), which was designed
>   to complement URLs by providing a mechanism for the identification of
>   resources in particular namespaces.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)